# how to have separated confidence intervals in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I have the following code in R.

```
df <- data.frame(Region = rep(1:3,3), education = rep(1:3,each =3),
                 mean = runif(9,0,1) , lo = runif(9, -1 , 0), 
                 up = runif(9, 1, 2))

ggplot(df, aes(Region, mean)) + geom_point(size=4) +
 geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lo, ymax = up))
```

As you can see, the confidence intervals intersect each other. But, what I want is to have three different confidence interval beside each other separated by the variable education, and possibly with three different colors. The same way we separate bar graphs by another categorical variables

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Region = rep(1:3,3), education = rep(1:3,each =3),
                 mean = runif(9,0,1) , lo = runif(9, -1 , 0), 
                 up = runif(9, 1, 2))

df$RegEdu <- with(df, interaction(Region,  education), drop = TRUE )

ggplot(df, aes(x=RegEdu, y=mean, colour=factor(education), 
       pch=factor(Region))) + geom_point(size=4) +
       geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lo, ymax = up))
```

[image]

**EDIT.**
Using `facet_grid` you can group together error bars by `education`

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Region, y=mean, colour=factor(education))) + 
       geom_point(size=4) +
       geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lo, ymax = up))+
       facet_grid(.~education)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @marco Sandri. It helps a lot, but do you know if I there is any way to group each three together. I mean make the first three (1.1, 2.1, 3.1) closer together to show that they belong to one group, and so on,

Comment: Thank you so much @Marco Sandri. It really helped. Unfortunately, I can't upvote you as I don't have enough reputation

Comment: Sorry @Marco Sandri, But I still don't have enough reputation to upvote you :(
When I upvote you, it says that the vote is recorded, but it does not change the public score :(
Sorry!